# How to use DataTemplate with FrameworkContentElement?

Tags: wpf

For some reasons, I have to implement WPF controls using the FrameworkContentElement subclass.

### My question is

How do I use a DataTemplate with my own elements that inherits the FrameworkContentElement class? Or do I have to re-implement my own DataTemplate?

### About the reason

I'm using WPF to make a 3d-rendering  Control and I want my scene graph that is used by this Control to be described like others WPF controls to make easy Bindings with MVVM.

I implemented these Controls with FrameworkElement but I had big performance issues with the Measure method which, in my case, I don't even use!

So, I found on the web that FrameworkContentElement is what I'm looking for since it does not make any Measure calculations. But on another hand, it does not seem to be using common useful elements such as DataTeamplates, ItemsControls, ContentControls, etc...

So if you have any suggestions, don't hesitate to answer!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing few things about WPF.

FrameworkElement doesn't support DataTemplates. FrameworkElement supports only styles which also does FrameworkContentElement too. Thats basically it.

FrameworkElement and FrameworkContentElement only support basics in WPF.

CustomControls in WPF support DataTempates. CustomControls are ContentControl or ItemsControl but also Button, ListBox, DataGrid... Those controls inherit from ContentControl or ItemsControl and use the properties ContentTemplate or ItemsTemplate for DataTemplate purposes.

FrameworkContentElement is sort of a FrameworkElement just without layouting and rendering. You can call it FrameworkElement light with zero sugar.

When dealing with FrameworkContentElements you basically need to write all by yourself in order to support rendering or for example fully funcional VisualTree and LogicalTree. That is the reason why Microsoft only uses FrameworkContentElement for defining how should text be displayed in documents. Thats the main purpose of FrameworkContentElement. Text has no futher children and therefore it doesn't need to measure or arrange them or neither it needs a fully functional VisualTree/LogicalTree. Text is just... its just text and it only needs to be rendered.

Now to answer your question if you want DataTemplates you would need to have sort of a new class that inherits from FrameworkContentElement and that provides properties for defining custom DataTemplates. However those elements which are later going to be inside DataTemplates will need layouting and rendering since they are probably going to be of type UiElement. So you are going to end up writing measuring and arranging logic anyways for those elements inside DataTemplates. Finally, once you managed to provide your DataTemplates with layouting logic you will realize that you reinvented ContentControl. Futhermore that is the point where you also going to realize you are having those layout performance issues again.

To sum up DataTemplates in FrameworkContentControl usually won't work properly because DataTemplates may contain UiElements and UiElements need layouting...

So the true question is how to trick out Wpf.

Well how about you have a class that inherits from FrameworkElement and you override the Measure and Arrange methods???

Inside those two you may choose when shall rendering take place and when shall it be skpped for performance gain.

Comment: The FrameworkElement class does not allow to override the Measure and Arrange methods. It only allows override of MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride. The point is: I don't want any Measure/Arrange calculations and overriding MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride does not bypass the whole Measure/Arrange process that is coded inside FrameworkElement.

I read [HERE](http://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html) that UiElement implement LIFE. What I want is a class without the 'L' (for layout) part.

Comment: When I said to override measure and arrange I ment to override the MeasureOverride method and ArrangeOverride method. When layouting first MeasureCore is being called and then MeasureOverride. If in MeasureOverride no futher measure on kids is being called there will be no futher measuring at all. That is how you can define that FrameworkElement has no futher measuring to do. That would be it. There wont be any impact on layout performance if you return always the same value for size. However this was just a suggest to override those two.

Comment: FrameworkContentElement shouldnt contain any futher children because its ment to be a child and not a parent. Its just there so you can define your own custom rendering and therefore it doesnt support layouting and other features in first place. Its there to be used as child and not as parent... metaphorically speaking :)