# When is DataTemplate used in ContentControl and ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf

I have WPF controls that I created that inherits the FrameworkElement class. One of them is done like this:

```
[ContentProperty("Children")]
public class ItemsElement : FrameworkElement
{
    public ItemsElement()
    {
        Children = new UIElementCollection(this, this);
    }

    public UIElementCollection Children { get; private set; }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get
        {
            if (Children != null)
            {
                return Children.Count;
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        return Children[index];
    }

    protected override IEnumerator LogicalChildren
    {
        get
        {
            if (Children != null)
            {
                return Children.GetEnumerator();
            }

            return EmptyEnumerator.Instance;
        }
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        return availableSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        return finalSize;
    }
}
```

What I want with this code is to have elements that are not 2D-UI elements. I overrided the Measure and Arrange methods so that it does not compute Sizes of the Children. This is a behavior that I want because these computations are heavy and useless.

The problem is if I put ContentControls and ItemsControls in the Children of my ItemsElement class (through XAML), these controls do not seem to generate their Visual children from Content/ItemsSource with the DataTemplate I defined for them in the Resources.

It does work if I add this code at the beginning of the MeasureOverride method:

```
foreach (UIElement child in Children)
{
    child.Measure(availableSize);
}
```

I can't understand why...

Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question really is *why are you extending a class who's behaviour you don't want?* The answer is too long for here, but you can read it in full in the [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN. But to answer in short, I can only assume that you are extending the wrong class. Maybe you don't even need to extend any class.

In WPF, there are *many* alternatives to writing a new control. Often the only real need to do that is to perform some special custom drawing for a unique control that cannot be composed by other means. As the linked page says, *WPF enables you to customize existing controls by using its rich content model, styles, templates, and triggers*. Further on it continues:

> Controls that derive from UserControl or Control rely upon composing existing elements. For many scenarios, this is an acceptable solution, because any object that inherits from FrameworkElement can be in a ControlTemplate. However, there are times when a control's appearance requires more than the functionality of simple element composition. For these scenarios, basing a component on FrameworkElement is the right choice.

Finally, the `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` methods are required to be implemented correctly in order for the `FrameworkElement` to render its items. You just need to look at MSDN to find this basic information out. From the [`FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page:

> Your implementation should do the following:
> 1.Iterate your element's particular collection of children that are part of layout, call Measure on each child element.

And from the [`FrameworkElement.ArrangeOverride` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.arrangeoverride%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page:

> Parent elements should call Arrange on each child, otherwise the child elements will not be rendered.

Please read the linked pages for further information and in future, please look in MSDN for information regarding your problem control, method, event, etc. *before* asking questions here.

---

UPDATE >>>

In response to your somewhat offensive comment, I can see you *do* have a valid reason to extend the `FrameworkElement` class, but that doesn't change anything. You *say* that you've read all the pages that I showed you, but for some reason, you *haven't* followed the clear instructions on what you *have* to do to render the items correctly.

There's no need to answer your question regarding the `DataTemplate` and when exactly it is rendered because it is irrelevant to your problem. Your problem is caused simply because you have not followed the instructions found on MSDN in your class. That's it. One thing that you can check to see if this is correct or not is this.

If you see the full name of the type of objects in the collection when you run your application, then you have a problem with your `DataTemplate` not being applied. However, if you see no items, then you have a problem with your rendering and that's simply because you haven't implemented those two essential methods correctly.

Comment: Please see [this post of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894063/how-to-use-datatemplate-with-frameworkcontentelement) to know why I'm extending FrameworkElement rather than anything else. You told me to read MSDN documentation, I already did and saw what you 'explained', but you didn't answer my question which is: When is DataTemplate used in ContentControl and ItemsControl? That is to say inside the implementation of the Measure method which is a black box to me. If it's not to help, don't say anything.

Comment: Be careful with your comments. When any user takes the time to answer a question, it is inappropriate to take that attitude. If you look at your question again, you'll see that you *actually* asked this about the `MeasureOverride` method: *I can't understand why... Do you have any idea?* That is what I was answering, so maybe you need to edit your question to be clearer about what you *actually* want to know, rather than insulting a senior member of this website.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was a little pissed off by your answer "Read the documentation, little noob." But I realized that the original question is not well written... So, again sorry!

Comment: So now, to go farthest: I understand I have to correctly implement the MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride methods to make the DataTemplates work. The point is I don't want the system to run the Measure and Arrange algorithms because they are too expensive and useless in my special case (I have a heavy 3d-scene graph and it is not displayed in the UI). Maybe I should make another question for that?

Comment: That *does* sound worthy of a new question and please provide as much relevant information as you can.